# Replace a Wordpress (WooCommerce) Function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the Unite Theme with Woocommerce and need to replace the wc_get_product_cat_class function. After an entire night trying to figure it out, I have found that the following is stored in /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php

```
//  Display the classes for the product cat div.
    function wc_product_cat_class( $class = '', $category = null){
     // Separates classes with a single space, collates classes for post DIV
     echo 'class="' . esc_attr( join( ' ', wc_get_product_cat_class( $class, $category ) ) ) . '"';
    }
//  Get the classes for the product cat div.
    function wc_get_product_cat_class( $class = '', $category = null ){
     global $woocommerce_loop;
     $classes   = is_array( $class ) ? $class : array_map( 'trim', explode( ' ', $class ) );
     $classes[] = 'product';
     if ( 0 === ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] - 1 ) % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] || 1 === $woocommerce_loop['columns'] ) {
      $classes[] = 'first';
     }
     if ( 0 === $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] ) {
      $classes[] = 'last';
     }
     $classes = apply_filters( 'product_cat_class', $classes, $class, $category );
     return array_unique( array_filter( $classes ) );
    }
```

I have already created a functions.php file in my child theme already.  How do I remove and replace the wc_get_product_cat_class function?

As I understand it the functions.php file in the child theme loads first, but in the absence of a if(! line in the wc-template-functions.php, I am unable to simple add and amend the above to my own functions file.

Comment: Why would you need to replace it when you could filter `product_cat_class`? And what modifications do you need to make?

Comment: I need to replace and add to the classes generated.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question to explain which classes you need to modify? That is *exactly* the point of the filter, so replacing the function seems like overkill.

Comment: The filter adds a class which is applied to the product loop on one of the achive pages.  I need to add a class for the bootstrap columns col-xs-2 col-md-4 etc.

Comment: When are you trying to add those classes? Ie. what class goes where?

Comment: on the li in the loop, do you know how to replace or add to this function from another function? I don't want to edit this function in the file it is in, in case of a woocommerce or wordpress update, if I did I would have fixed this days ago.

Comment: I meant which `li` gets the `col-xs-2` class and so forth.

Comment: I can see that the function takes an existing array, converts it to a comma separated format, then over rights the array, adding the original comma separated values back in and ensures everything is unique. My question is how do I replace this function in my child theme functions.php file?

Comment: You don't. That's why I can't answer the question "as asked". What you *can* do is use the filter to modify the classes in the array. See my example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to filter the product classes via `product_cat_class`. I don't know exactly where you want the specific classes to appear so this is just an example. Note, `$woocommerce_loop['loop']` is the position/count of the item in the loop. And it isn't in this example, but you can see it in the core `wc_get_product_cat_class()` function.... `$woocommerce['columns'] is the number of columns aka products per row.

```
function so_35164526_cat_class( $classes, $class, $category= null ){
    global $woocommerce_loop;
    if ( 0 === $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % 4 ) {
        $classes[] = 'col-md-4';
    } elseif ( 0 === $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % 2 ) {
        $classes[] = 'col-xs-2 ';
    } 
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'product_cat_class', 'so_35164526_cat_class', 10, 3 );
```